# RSSFeed exception in Android

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse, exception

i want to view the news in my textbox in my device on Android i have get the xml data but i can't parse my data to get my news

***RSSFeedActivity Class***

> 

```
public class RSSFeedActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView a5bar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        a5bar = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Data_feed);
        String feed = "http://www.masrawy.com/News/rss/LocalPolitics.aspx";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(feed);

        try {
            HttpResponse response =   client.execute(request);
            StatusLine st_line = response.getStatusLine();
            int statuescode = st_line.getStatusCode();
            if(statuescode ==200){

                InputStream jsonstream = response.getEntity().getContent();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonstream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){
                    builder.append(line);
                }
                String js_data = builder.toString();
                a5bar.setText(js_data);

                try{
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(js_data);
                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id=json_data.getString("CNN");
                        Log.i("Feed", id);
                    }
                }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                }

            }


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater m_i_f = getMenuInflater();
        m_i_f.inflate(R.menu.cool_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.aboutus:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Developed by Islam hamdy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        case R.id.reference:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Go To My blog", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

***xmlfile***

```
>     > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout
>     > xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     >     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     >     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     >     android:orientation="vertical" >
>     > 
>     > 
>     >     <TextView
>     >         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     >         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     >         android:layout_gravity="center"
>     >         android:text="@string/hello" 
>     >         android:id="@+id/Data_feed"
>     >         />
>     > 
>     >      </LinearLayout>
```

when i get data it's like a website xml and the language didn't appear

Comment: What is the specific problem? Also please pay attention to formatting to make the code readable.

Comment: am sorry i make it readable now

Comment: using xml for data transport for mobile devices requires upto 60% more bandwidth please consider using JSON as an alternative for saving bandwidth.

Comment: can you edit this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse an XML response with the code that parses JSON which is a blunder. I would recommend using a hosted server to convert the xml response to JSON. The php code to do that would be.

```
<?php
$url="your_url_here";
$fileContents= file_get_contents($url);
$fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
$fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
$json = json_encode($simpleXml);
echo $json;
?>
```

host this somewhere and call this page to convert your feed this will result in lower bandwidth consumption for the mobile client. Once you get this done parse the response like you have done in your code!

And moreover your code tries to do Network operations on its main thread. Which is highly discouraged! Try that above android 2.3 your app would crash right away! Please refer to using the AsyncTask class for avoiding doing long running operations on the main thread!

Comment: so i can't parse xml data without this code???

Comment: you can.. you can use several libraries that help parsing XML !but using XML for data transports for mobile devices is heavy on bandwidth! i suggest you to use JSON. it is 60% lightweight than xml. search for yourself you'll know the difference.

Comment: can you tell me about this libraries ???

Comment: i already use json if you see my code you find that i use json

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html read this.

Comment: i want to use json like my code above

Comment: Ive seen that but the url you are requesting replies back with xml data! this one :: http://www.masrawy.com/News/rss/LocalPolitics.aspx

Comment: Then host the code above in a live webserver. ive hosted the php script to achieve just like what you want here : http://dev.smarttech.com.np/api
host the code and change the url to your xml feed source! then work on getting the feed!

Comment: can you edit my code to parse my data ???